# Systeme package

Tags: math-mode, mtpro, systeme

I am using the [`systeme`](https://ctan.org/pkg/systeme) package to create an equation system.
I am also using the [`mtpro2`](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package for mathematical notation.

When I want to create a 2x2 system with a curly bracket, it works just fine by using the command `\sysdelim\{.`.
But, it seems that the curly bracket doesn't look the same in a 3x3 system or above.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{psfrag}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{mtpro2}
 \usepackage{calc}
 \usepackage{systeme}

 \begin{document}
 \sysdelim\{.\systeme{2x+3y=5,x-4y=-3\quad}
 \sysdelim\{.\systeme[xzy]{2x+3y-z=5,x+2z-4y=-3,x+y=2}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make the 2nd bracket look like the 1st?

**EDIT 2020 - TeXLive issue after update 10/4/2020**

I have just updated my TeXLive distribution to TexLive 2020 and tried to run the same code using the patch recommended by egreg at the second part of his answer. Apparently there is a new issue

> LaTeX3 Error: '\msg_term:n' deprecated on 2020-01-01. Use '\iow_term:n '. {}{}

Where exactly must I replace that code?

Comment: `\usepackage[straightbraces]{mtpro2}` should do.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted the 2nd to look like the 1st which is curly!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want those pesky curly braces, load the package with the `straightbraces` option:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite,straightbraces]{mtpro2} % lite because I only have that
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\[
\systeme{2x+3y=5,x-4y=-3}      
\quad
\systeme[xzy]{2x+3y-z=5,x+2z-4y=-3,x+y=2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\sysdelim\{.` is the default.

If you prefer the pesky braces, you have to use `\LEFTRIGHT`, so an indirect path must be followed:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % lite because I only have that
\usepackage{systeme,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\csysteme}{som}{%
  \LEFTRIGHT\{.{%
    \sysdelim..
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\systeme*{#3}}{\systeme*[#2]{#3}}}
     {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\systeme{#3}}{\systeme[#2]{#3}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\csysteme{2x+3y=5,x-4y=-3}
\quad
\csysteme[xzy]{2x+3y-z=5,x+2z-4y=-3,x+y=2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a patch one can avoid changing syntax; the idea is to use `\LEFTRIGHT` of `mtpro2` instead of `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{systeme,regexpatch}

\makeatletter
% change the definition of \sysdelim not to store `\left` and `\right`
\def\sysdelim#1#2{\def\SYS@delim@left{#1}\def\SYS@delim@right{#2}}
\sysdelim\{. % reinitialize

% patch the internal command to use
% \LEFTRIGHT<left delim><right delim>{<system>}
% instead of \left<left delim<system>\right<right delim>
\regexpatchcmd\SYS@systeme@iii
  {\cB.\c{SYS@delim@left}(.*)\c{SYS@delim@right}\cE.}
  {\c{SYS@MT@LEFTRIGHT}\cB\{\1\cE\}}
  {}{}
\def\SYS@MT@LEFTRIGHT{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\LEFTRIGHT
  \expandafter\SYS@delim@left\SYS@delim@right}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\systeme{2x+3y=5,x-4y=-3}
\quad
\systeme[xzy]{2x+3y-z=5,x+2z-4y=-3,x+y=2}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the opposite.The straight bracket to look like the 1st one which is curly. To create curly bracket also for the 3x3 system.

Comment: @mac I was just adding a more complex solution that should avoid changing syntax.

Comment: I can see that the alignment of the variables has changed and x is under z which didnt happen before the new code.Is there any way we can fix that?Thanks.

Comment: @mac I switched the `*` position, sorry! I'll fix it immediately!

Comment: It works perfect!That was a lot of work!Thanks!