# Improper alphabetic constant with systeme

Tags: mtpro, systeme

I recently installed `miktex` in a new computer and I had to set everything up from the beginning. The following mwe is working just fine in my old computer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfontsb}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

%--------------------------
\usepackage{systeme,regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% change the definition of \sysdelim not to store `\left` and `\right`
\def\sysdelim#1#2{\def\SYS@delim@left{#1}\def\SYS@delim@right{#2}}
\sysdelim\{. % reinitialize
% patch the internal command to use
% \LEFTRIGHT<left delim><right delim>{<system>}
% instead of \left<left delim<system>\right<right delim>
\regexpatchcmd\SYS@systeme@iii
{\cB.\c{SYS@delim@left}(.*)\c{SYS@delim@right}\cE.}
{\c{SYS@MT@LEFTRIGHT}\cB\{\1\cE\}}
{}{}
\def\SYS@MT@LEFTRIGHT{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\LEFTRIGHT
    \expandafter\SYS@delim@left\SYS@delim@right}
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\[ \systeme{x,y,z} \]

\end{document}
```

Between the comment lines there is a patch for `systeme` package that I use in order to get curly braces using the `mtpro2` package as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181037/systeme-package). It works just fine too in every document (in my old computer). But in the new installation I get the following error :

```
Improper alphabetic constant. {}{}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry for that; a change in `l3` made for an inaccurate test. A fix is in the working and should be uploaded in a couple of days. Do you have any urgency?

Comment: Not really. I will try to update this package when its ready.

Comment: @mac Update will go tonight, CTAN then need ~24 h then MiKTeX/TL another ~24 h.

Comment: @mac The good thing is that many people using `l3` means easier and faster bug fixing. Thanks to the team and Joseph in particular.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem it's due to a bug that will be fixed in a couple of days.

Comment: With this morning update the problem appears to be solved.

Comment: Can't locate the updated package. Is there any link?

Comment: I found the packages and it works fine thanks!