# How to use \begin{cases}

Tags: cases

I need to do some work, I know the command  \begin{cases} do this symbol "{" at the beggining of the operation, but now I need the other one, "}" that symbol, at the end of the operation.
How can I do that?
I want this:
[image: This is what I want]

And I know how to do this:

[image: Not wanna learn how to do this]

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't use `systeme` package? See  [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181054/87876).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Using `rcases` as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559789) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer, `systeme` is quite fickle, better use an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left.
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
  x +{}&& y ={}&& 7\\
  5x -{}&& 2y ={}&& -7
  \end{alignedat}
  \right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks men, I just started so this helps a LOT. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 2):

The package `systeme` does wonders for linear systems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\sysdelim{.}{\rbrace}
\systeme{
  x+y=7,
  5x-2y=-7
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want right alignment for the right-hand sides, you can use the relevant option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\sysdelim{.}{\rbrace}
\sysalign{r,r}
\systeme{
  x+y=7,
  5x-2y=-7
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out [How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases), I think it has what you're looking for.

An alternative to the `cases` environment is to use an `aligned` environment from `amsmath` with `\left\{` and `\right\}` braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\[
\left.
    \begin{aligned}
        x + y   &= 7 \\
        5x - 2y &= -7
    \end{aligned}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks men, It really helps, I just started (this week) learning how to do this stuff so I really appreciate it.